# Could not find or load main class : Executable JAR from Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create an executable JAR from Maven with maven-assembly-plugin. My Jars are getting created but without my source code. I have already mentioned goal as single in POM and creating jar with this command: "`mvn clean package assembly:single`".  But I am still getting this error: "Error: Could not find or load main class com.som.bau.report.MainClass".

[image]

Please see below my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>VFIE_SOM_BAU_Report</groupId>
<artifactId>SOM_BAU_Report</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.som.bau.report.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> 
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<!-- Dependencies code goes here ---!>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure your main class is com.som.bau.report.MainClass ?

Comment: Yes I have main method in this class and it works if I directly execute it from eclipse

Comment: also attach directory structure in question

Comment: attached.......

Comment: @ManishRajput have you checked your target/classes folder, is your .class files there or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You should append packaging type to root element.

```
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>VFIE_SOM_BAU_Report</groupId>  
<artifactId>SOM_BAU_Report</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
```

Comment: Doesn't `packaging` default to `jar`?

Comment: İn the target folder there are two jar files. Be sure run right jar.

Comment: I am executing the right one. Issue is both of the jars doesn't have my source code

Comment: ok. can you list files in jar with jar tf package.jar command then you will check it. is it everything is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it.

Need to add this tag under build tag.

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

Comment: You should have rather put your sources under src/main/java, which is the default assumption from Maven